# Why use ? : operator in a for loop in java was marked no a statement?

Tags: java, hashmap

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Solution549_LongestHarmony {

    public int findLHS(int[] nums) {
        int longest = 0;
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        //fill the map
        for (Integer i : nums) {
            map.containsKey(i) ? map.replace(i, map.get(i) + 1) : map.put(i, 1);
        }

        for (Integer i : nums) {
            if (map.containsKey(i + 1)) {
                longest = Math.max(longest, map.get(i) + map.get(i + 1));
            }
        }
        if (map != null) {
            map.remove(2);
        }
        return longest;

    }
}
```

error information:

```
Line 7: error: not a statement
            map.containsKey(i) ? map.replace(i, map.get(i)+1):map.put(i,1);
```

Comment: You wrote an expression. It's syntactically  similar to `3 +2`, which will be a valid expression but not a statement.

Comment: Your title does not make sense grammatically.

Comment: I'll answer your question with a question: Why didn't you just write an `if-else` statement? --- Better yet: Why not use `compute()` or `merge()`?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @PM 77-1 too, the error message clearly states that

```
a ? b : c
```

is *not a statement* but an *expression*. You would need an assignment or a method call that uses the expression value to have a statement that compiles successfully.

```
someVar = a ? b : c;
someMethod(a ? b : c);
```

So, you can populate your map with a statement like

```
map.put(i, map.containsKey(i) ? map.get(i) + 1 : 1);
```

Comment: Please show your appreciation by accepting the answer if it worked for you. Click on the **tick**. It will turn green.